# Change color background in Microsoft To Do

Tags: microsoft-to-do

Microsoft [advertises color backgrounds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=talW1utQN_M&feature=emb_title) in its Microsoft To Do (RIP Wunderlist) but I don't see a setting for changing it in the web app. Am I missing something?

[image: img via Apple Store, not cc-by]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=talW1utQN_M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web app currently doesn't have the background feature, the advertised colour backgrounds are from native application.

For Example:
In windows application you can select any list and go to the 3 dots on top right hand side  and you will get the option to choose the background and these changes get synced to your mobile application too, but nothing on the web app.

[image]